# How do I uninstall all user installed python and pip versions?

Tags: python, pip

Originally asked [at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913770/how-do-i-uninstall-all-user-installed-python-and-pip-versions).

There are several python2 and python3 versions installed when I cheched /usr/bin/ directory. I want to uninstall all user installed versions of python and leave only the version already coming with the operating system (to avoid any adverse effects). Then I want to install latest python2 and python3 through some version manager.

How do I uninstall all of the user installed versions and associated pip(s) ? to install newest versions of python using a version manager like pyenv or something. My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913770/how-do-i-install-all-user-installed-python-and-pip-versions#48913770

Comment: @Silencer310 I asked that stackoverflow question minutes ago, and someone suggested to ask it here, because I use Ubuntu.

Comment: I linked it because posting without interlinking means you can get an answer on one site, but people not attending the other site might still be working on a solution somewhere else, wasting their time

Comment: Oh, OK. I'll mention in the question.